# Overload Enum in SilverStripe DataExtension

Tags: php, enums, silverstripe

Is it possible to overload an Enum field using a DataExtension?

```
class Order extends DataObject {
    private static $db=array('Status'=>"Enum('Unpaid, Paid','Unpaid')";
}

class OrderExtension extends DataExtension {
    private static $db=array('Status'=>"Enum('Unpaid, Paid, Cancelled','Unpaid')"; //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Assuming you've applied `OrderExtension` to `Order` in configuration, and that the missing `)` at the end is only a typo in the example?

Comment: Have you tried to run dev/build with this? What happened? Either SS wll complain on dev/build that you're trying to add a column of the same name or it will modify the field's column config.

Don't forget to update `_config/config.yml` or `_config/extensions.yml` with a ref to your new decorator, or SS's class manifest will have no knowledge of your class.

Comment: RobbieAverill - Yeah just typos in my example.

@theruss - I was sure I had my extension in config.yml and did a dev/build but it didn't do anything. No complaints from SS either. I'm going to test it out again today.

Thank you both.

Comment: Double checked, extension is definitely working but Status is not being updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to get the augmentDatabase() method to work, but after speaking with a colleague he suggested using config.yml and this did the trick.

```
Order:
    db:
        Status: Enum('Unpaid, Paid, Cancelled','Unpaid')
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears not to be possible using the methods we've discussed so far. I implemented the OP's code and found the same thing, that the table of the decorated object ("Order" in this case) was not updated as expected.

I can sort of reason as to why this is not implemented via a `DataExtension` given that dev's may screw with some core logic that relies on specific table and column specs.

I did a little digging and found that what OP wants *is* possible, but with a bit of code. Looking at the following page: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/reference/dataextension/#custom-database-generation it suggests defining an `augmentDatabase()` method on the custom `DataExtension`.

However, there don't seem to be any detailed docs on what to do next. Instead the page above advises to check out the core `Versioned` extension which, after grepping my entire SS project, is the only `DataExtension` subclass I could find that declared an `augmentDatabase()` method. Given that `Versioned` needs to deal with x3 tables for each class it decorates (`SiteTree`, `SiteTree_Live`, `SiteTree_versions`) then its logic is bound to be quite involved. I suspect however that for a custom implementation on a DataObject, things may be a little simpler. (Unless you're versioning DataObjects too that is!).

Good luck :-)

Comment: The link you provided is redirecting to a different page. I'm wondering if you could find the original link/page?

I found [https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4.0/developer_guides/model/data_types_and_casting/#overloading](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4.0/developer_guides/model/data_types_and_casting/#overloading) which mentions using get<fieldname> or set<fieldname>. Again, it doesn't say exactly how to do this.

Comment: Sorry chap, I can't find that page anymore. Not sure about you, but I work better from working examples than step by step docs :-) basically; AFAIKT `augmentDatabase()` will perform the changes you make to the DB with that method on dev/build. So look at `Versioned` and what you can make it do :-)

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks again.