# How can I add a new enum value to an existing enum field?

Tags: silverstripe, silvershop

I am using the silvershop-core module and I want to add an additional order status to the existing `Order.Status` enum field.
How can I do that?

I have already tried the `DataExtension` approach, but it did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overload Enum in SilverStripe DataExtension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352714/overload-enum-in-silverstripe-dataextension)

Answer (score 3):

You can override individual `db` fields via YAML config. So in `mysite/_config/config.yml` put something like this:

```
Order:
  db:
    Status: "Enum('MyStatus,Unpaid,Paid,Processing,Sent,Complete,AdminCancelled,MemberCancelled,Cart','Cart')"
```

As you can see, `MyStatus` was added to the enum. It's important that you keep all the other statuses though (as some code might depend on them), so best copy the field definition from the class you want to override (in this case `Order`) and add the additional enum value(s) to that.